# How to find duration from google fit api in ionic4?

Tags: ionic4

I am developing fitness app using google fit APIs. In which I am calculating distance, steps, calories and duration. All the details have been found apart from duration. How can I find duration using google fit api ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From googleFit api, you will find `startDate` and `endDate`.

You will have to get the time difference and add them together.

First import googlefit service:

```
import { GoogleFitService } from "../../core/services/google-fit.service";
```

Declare it into constructor:

```
constructor(
 private googleFit: GoogleFitService
) { }
```

Get duration data:

```
this.googleFit.query().then(res => {
 let totalDiff = 0;
 for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
   totalDiff =
     totalDiff +
     (res[i].endDate.getTime() -
       res[i].startDate.getTime()); // milliseconds
 }
 let seconds: any = (totalDiff / 1000).toFixed(0);
});
```